# React component working with dynamic data but not with static data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react component which **works with dynamic data** which is an array, but its **not working with the same array if I pass it statically**. I could not figure out it.

Array is `[ { data: [ [ 1650931200000, 92.92520141449552 ], [ 1651363200000, 90.94800749520344 ], [ 1651449600000, 92.75263509391628 ] ], pointStart: 1650931200000, pointInterval: 86400000 } ]`

Comment: You should add some code related to the component at hand

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).